# How to include in a codelite project a file.txt

Tags: r

I'm new here, and I have a big problem: **I'm not able to include in my Codelite project an external text file**, in these files I have information about flights and booking.

This is the contents of `flights.txt`:

```
AA201 BLQ MAD 150 55.80
AA202 MPX AMS 110 79.00
AA203 MAD OPO 40 23.00
AA204 AES BLQ 170 94.67
AA205 STN CDG 80 47.50
AA205 BLQ MUN 100 120.20
BA001 ARN BRU 90 134.99
BA201 FCO ATH 125 78.00
CC222 MAD CDG 110 45.14
CA234 EIN OSL 70 80.20
FV897 RIX DUB 200 150.32
CD111 DME BLQ 190 105.30
GG000 BCN RAK 180 100.23
```

This is the contents of `booking.txt`:

```
AA201 Mark_Riesling A 2 111.6
AA205 Carl_Donahue R 1 123.5
CD111 Eric_Carter R 3 821.34
BA001 Alice_McKenzie A 4 539.96
AA203 Sarah_Lansbury A 1 23.00
FV897 Katie_Smith R 2 781.66
```

A function must open these files in read mode and must assign these information to structs which I have defined.
**How can I include these files to my project? Must be They located in the folder that Codelite created which contains main.c and header files?**

Answer (score 0):

> How can I include these files to my project?

Right click on the folder (e.g. `src`) and select `Add an existing file`

> Must be They located in the folder that Codelite created which contains main.c and header files?

No

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the **src** folder.
2. Click on **Add a New File**.
3. Name the file and add **.txt** in the end.
4. Copy and paste your information the the files you created.